# Parse variable to new queue job

Tags: craft3, queue, console, commands

Is there a way to parse a variable to a queue job? I want to re-send some Craft commerce emails via a cron job, so have created a console controller for the cron job to run a command against. This then will get all the customers to email and create a queued job (I'd like the jobs to run automatically somehow).
To save having one big job to email 100's of customers, I thought to create 1 job per customer ... only way I can think is to have the controller parse the customer email through each new job it creates.

I'm currently testing with sending a email to a sandbox email account in 1 queued job that loops through a `range` of 1-10. This method is becoming too unreliable where I might get emails 1-5 out of 10, or 1-5 then 15-20 in a loop of 20. The test I've just run only sent 18-20 out of 20.
When I've tested with creating a job per email, I get a consistent amount of emails.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass through the customer ID to your queue job, then the job itself can look up the customer and send the email.

Here's a super-simple example console controller action method that passes through a user ID to a queue job class called `SendEmail`:

```
public function actionSend()
{
    $userIds = User::find()
        ->status(User::STATUS_ACTIVE)
        ->ids();
    
    foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
        Craft::$app->getQueue()->delay(0)->push(new SendEmail([
            'userId' => $userId
        ])); 
    }
}
```

Then here's the `SendEmail` job class. This has a property called `userId` which represents the variable that's passed in when the new instance of the `SendEmail` class is created in the code example above. You can use that `userId` property to fetch the User object, and then send an email:

```
class SendEmail extends BaseJob
{
    // Public Properties
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $userId;

    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @param QueueInterface|Queue $queue
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute($queue)
    {  
        $user = Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserById($this->userId);

        if ($user) {
            Craft::$app->getMailer()
                ->composeFromKey('my-plugin_email_key, [
                    'firstName' => $user->firstName,
                ])
                ->setTo($user)
                ->send();
        }

        $this->setProgress($queue, 1);
    }

    // Protected Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function defaultDescription(): string
    {
        return Craft::t(
            'my-plugin',
            'Sending email for user Id {userId}',
            [
                'userId' => $this->userId,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I've left out the `namespace` and `use` statements etc., but hopefully that gives you an idea of how this works.

You'll need to register the email you want to send in your plugin/module's base class. I do this via a `_registerEmailMessages` class called from the plugin/module's `init` method:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    self::$plugin = $this;

    // Do a bunch of init stuff
    $this->_registerEmailMessages();
}

private function _registerEmailMessages()
{
    Event::on(
        SystemMessages::class,
        SystemMessages::EVENT_REGISTER_MESSAGES,
        function(RegisterEmailMessagesEvent $event) {
            $event->messages = array_merge($event->messages, [
                [
                    'key' => 'my-plugin_email_key',
                    'heading' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'my-plugin_email_key_heading'),
                    'subject' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'my-plugin_email_key_subject'),
                    'body' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'my-plugin_email_key_body'),
                ],
           ]);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I just came on to post my own answer, but your's is definitely better presented!
  
Can I check the line:
`Craft::$app->getQueue()->delay(0)->push(new SendEmail([ 'userId' => $userId ]));`
  Would this process the job when it's added?

Comment: That depends on how you have your queue set up. I use the Async Queue plugin from Oliver Stark (https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue) to run the queue using background processes, so in my setup it wouldn't run straight away. In a stock setup, I believe it would be processed as soon as the next request (i.e. page load) to Craft was made.